# Why are umbrellas black?

Tags: radiation, visible-light, thermal-radiation

Why are umbrellas specifically in black? Of course we do have colored ones, but black is the majority. Is there any scientific reason behind it?

Comment: I'm in Japan. Here vast majority of umbrellas are white or transparent.

Comment: I would suspect that it has to do with them not showing up dirt as easily.

Comment: Everything goes with black. Seriously. There is no physical explanation.

Comment: It's cheap and fashionable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Physics answer

A black body at a temperature T, area A (on either side) will radiate heat by:
$$\dot{Q}_{radiated ,downwards}=\sigma A T^4$$. If incident radiations are of power $P$, then $$\dot{Q}_{body}=mc\frac{dT}{dt}=P-2\sigma AT^4$$ (the 2 comes into place because it radiates in both directions)

We can integrate this if we want, but we mainly want to qualitatively analyse it. From this equation, we can see that as time passes, temperature will increase to an equilibrium value ($T_{eq}=(P/2\sigma A)^{1/4}$). I am assuming that $P>2\sigma A T^4$ in this analysis (I've never seen an umbrella that feels hotter than direct sunlight). At this equilibrium value, you will receive heat $\sigma A T^4$, i.e., $\frac{P}{2}$.

For a non-black umbrella, assuming no transmitted heat, we have $e=a=1-r$ (coefficient of emission,absorption and reflection respectively). Out of incident heat power $P$, $aP$ is absorbed. The body radiates heat on either face as $e\sigma AT^4=a\sigma AT^4$. So we have $$\dot{Q}_{body}=mc\frac{dT}{dt}=aP-2a\sigma AT^4$$. From this, we get the same value of equilibrium temperature as for a black body. But, radiated heat power is $eA\sigma T^4$, so it will radiate less heat than the black umbrella onto you (Since both $T=T_{eq}$ are the same).

So paradoxically, we get that a black umbrella is the worst thing to use on a sunny day.

### IMHO

Black seems to be the majority because of a cultural bias. I'm assuming you're from India (by looking at your name). Since India was once a British territory, we can trace the use of black umbrellas back to the Brits. The Brits used to use black because black was considered formal attire (Black suits are actually the most uncomfortable from the physics point of view). This must have proliferated to India (Most British traditions have). Umbrellas before the British must've been colorful ([See the painting here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbrella#Indian_subcontinent)). If you take a look at Japanese umbrellas, they're all colorful. So black is really not the majority worldwide.

Comment: Since a black umbrella absorbs all light the fabric will get hotter than a white umbrella. So the black umbrella will radiate more infrared heat onto the user.

Comment: Yeah.. I'll add this to the answer. I sort of saw the radiation tag and wrote that part of the answer without thinking too much..

Comment: Love the historic explanation :) How true, or atleast how realistic!

Comment: I would add that it is a useful color for all social occasions, particularly in a country where it rains most of the time. I remember having a problem going to a funeral with a colored umbrella, I chose to get wet.One does not take red to funerals. Women have the all purpose "little black dress" too.

Comment: @annav Hmm, that could explain the Brit choice of umbrella color.. Though then it still boils down to why black is the formal color. In India, you wear white to a funeral.

Comment: your edited calculations cannot be right. At the beach, it is cooler under white umbrellas/shades, then under dark colored ones. What about reflection? A white surface will not get to the same T as a black one.

Comment: Beach umbrellas are much larger, and they change the temperature of the area underneath them. Which I haven't taken into account here (normal umbrellas are used while walking around, so no temperature gradient can be maintained). A white surface does reach the same temperature, just a bit slower, assuming no transmission.

Comment: Wait... Now I'm confused as well.. Is there any error in the equations? And what can I do to take relection into account (aside from writing absorbed power as $aP$. I can't see how reflection comes into the picture, except as a way to reduce absorption.

Comment: reflection reduces the watts/m^2 that are absorbed. If the umbrella has an area of 1 m^2 and the sun gives 1000watts/m^2 , the black one will take all the energy, the white one will probably reflect 50%, so less is absorbed in the fabric. If it were a fully reflecting one,aluminum foil, no heat would come below.

Comment: Yes, I've taken that into account. $a+r=1$, if $t=0$. So I've counted net power absorbed as $aP$; thus $rP$ or $P(1-a)$ is reflected. And now I figured out my mistake.

Comment: @annav The mistake was that though the equilibrium temperatures stay the same, the heat radiated by the white umbrella is $e<1$ times the heat radiated by the black one if both are at the same temperature.

Comment: Rather than writing "Edit: This is wrong...." it would be much better if you actually remove the wrong part from the answer entirely and replace it with the right information.

Comment: To be fair to the Brits, excessive sunlight is rarely causing problems here. :)